# How do I automatically create an Individual User Account in ASP.NET Core (targeting .NET 8) from the users AD security group membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm converting an old ASP.NET MVC project to ASP.NET Core MVC project and am completely confused about implementing the various authentication scenarios that are required.

The ASP.NET Core MVC project will always be hosted by our customers on IIS in a windows environment.

The project has 'normal' MVC Views and Web API endpoints.

I created the project using Individual User Accounts. I then scaffolded ASP.NET Core Identity and completed the database configuration.

Essentially I need to handle the following means of authentication:

**For a user 'logging on' to use MVC Razor pages:**

1. An unauthenticated user accesses the site and is able to log-in using a username and password (this is working with the ASP.Net Core Identity UI components out of the box). They will be assigned claims based on the Role chosen when they registered.
2. An unauthenticated user accesses the site. The site tries to find an existing application user by matching their AD username to an application username.

- If found the user will be authenticated and their claims added.
- If they are not found, the site gets the users AD information and looks at the security groups they are allocated to. There will be some mapping in place to allocate the user to 1 Role based on a hierarchy of security groups (i.e. if a user is in both 'users' and 'administrators' security groups they will be added to the 'administrators' role. Once it knows what Role to assign them to, it creates a new application user ( adding 'default' claims based on the role) and authenticates the user.

**For the Web API Controller Actions (which will be called by controllers within the project AND by external apps):**

3. An external app trying to access a Web API endpoint needs to be able to request a JWT Token (generated from a username & password by this project) and then use this in the authentication header when accessing the .
4. Controllers (and Ajax Javascript calls) within the project need to use the authentication that's already been used when they logged in.

Just to complicate things, a user needs to be able to tell the site to not try using method 2) and just allow them to log-on using method 1) (typing their username & password - in the old ASP.NET app we use ?IgnoreWindowsUsername=true in the query string).

And finally, because we need to have an easy method of logging on kiosk screens, we need a way of logging in using querystring values; e.g. https://app/?user=userid&password=pwd. I know this is horribly insecure, but don't know a better way of approaching this?

Apologies if I've got the terminology incorrect - our current solution uses third party modules for 'mixed-mode' authentication as it was called, with some modification to look-up AD information, but probably is not implemented 'correctly'.

Thanks